# Non persistent deployment with JBoss EAP 7 CLI

Tags: deployment, command-line-interface, jboss-eap-7

With the command line interface of JBoss (CLI) it is possible to [deploy an application](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html-single/management_cli_guide/#deploy_an_application_to_a_standalone_server) to a standalone server:

```
deploy /path/to/DEPLOYMENT.war
```

This is even possible to a remote application server. This deployment is persistent. It is registered in the configuration file `standalone*.xml` and the deployed file ist extracted under `data`.

However, we have the requirement that the deployment must be non persistent. The deployed file should be put into the directory `deployments`.

Is there a way to make a non persistent deployment using a **CLI command**?

We could

- split our CLI install file such that any configuration is done via CLI and the deployment happens over some file transfer protocol (this is not an CLI command and usually requires an extra port), or
- bundle the application with an CLI install file and deploy that bundle (read about it but can't find the documentation anymore)

Both solutions are possible but we would prefer a single CLI command if available.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `deploy --help`. There is an option for `--unmanaged` which is likely what you want.

```
 --unmanaged      - if this argument is not specified, the deployment content
                    will be copied (i.e. uploaded) to the server's deployment
                    repository before it is deployed. If the argument is
                    present, the deployment content will remain at and be
                    deployed directly from its original location specified with
                    the file_path.
                    NOTE: exploded deployments are supported only as unmanaged.
```

Comment: Does this work remotely too? As I understand the command's description with `--unmanaged` the application is not copied at all (execpt to "explode" the archive during startup). To get this working remotely I assume one has to copy the application EAR to the remote `deployments` directory at first -- something I would like to avoid.

Comment: We tried this parameter. It is not a solution for our requirement because it does not transfer the application to the `deployments` directory.

Comment: The `deployments` directory is *only* used for the `deployment-scanner`. See the `README` in there. You cannot deploy content to that directory with any management operations.